# Writing a python Matrix to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix

If I have a matrix as such:

```
A=
[['-', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
['A', '0', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
['B', '5', '0', '6', '7', '8'],
['C', '6', '6', '0', '7', '8'],
['D', '7', '7', '7', '0', '8'],
['E', '8', '8', '8', '8', '0']]
```

How can I create a text file containing the matrix in the following form? (or a similar sort of form so that it is more huma-readable):

```
- A B C D E
A 0 5 6 7 8
B 5 0 6 7 8
C 6 6 0 7 8
D 7 7 7 0 8
E 8 8 8 8 0
```

My attempt:

```
file1 = open("MyFile.txt","a")
A=
[['-', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
['A', '0', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
['B', '5', '0', '6', '7', '8'],
['C', '6', '6', '0', '7', '8'],
['D', '7', '7', '7', '0', '8'],
['E', '8', '8', '8', '8', '0']]

file1.writelines(str(A)) 
file1.close()
```

Comment: I downvoted, because it seems like that the OP didn't [attempted to try solving the problem themselves first](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: _If I have a matrix as such_ What’s the type of the object?

Comment: What have you tried and what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @Twenty I have updated the question to show my working out. Please take away the downvotes.

Comment: And in what way does your attempt fail to do what you want? Please read [ask].

Comment: I see that you have put effort in your question, I have removed my downvote. Just keep in mind to always share your attempts if possible.

Comment: Why does it have to be in such a specific format? Do you actually care about the format, or is that unimportant (because there are much better ways to write data like this to a file, but the format may not be human-readable). Is this homework?

Comment: @Z4-tier I chose this format because I personally thought it was more readable than just lists of lists. If you have a better way of formatting it then please do help.

Comment: you can use the `pickle` module to serialize the array to a file using `pickle.dump` and then you can read it back into python using `pickle.load` and it will give you back the same data, as lists, just like you had it originally. If you use your proposed format, reading it back will be very cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official documentation, [`writelines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) writes a *list* of lines to a file.

`str(A)` does not create a "list of lines" – obviously, when you print it to the screen – so the very first step should be to *create* a list-of-lines:

```
A=[
['-', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
['A', '0', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
['B', '5', '0', '6', '7', '8'],
['C', '6', '6', '0', '7', '8'],
['D', '7', '7', '7', '0', '8'],
['E', '8', '8', '8', '8', '0']]

print ([' '.join(row) for row in A])
```

which shows the 2D list has been flattened into a 1D list, with spaces separating the items:

```
['- A B C D E', 'A 0 5 6 7 8', 'B 5 0 6 7 8', 'C 6 6 0 7 8', 'D 7 7 7 0 8', 'E 8 8 8 8 0']
```

and so you can dump it into a file:

```
with open("MyFile.txt","w") as file1:
    file1.writelines ([' '.join(row)+'\n' for row in A])
```

(per the documentation, you are required to add a newline at the end yourself) with the required result:

```
- A B C D E
A 0 5 6 7 8
B 5 0 6 7 8
C 6 6 0 7 8
D 7 7 7 0 8
E 8 8 8 8 0
```

or, alternatively, using `write` only:

```
with open("MyFile.txt","w") as file1:
    file1.write ('\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in A))
```